# PC crashes (hangs) when playing games unless I do a reset beforehand

Tags: windows, crash, gaming

I've tried debugging this for a few months now.  I've disabled all services and startup programs, changed hardware for identical copies and have narrowed the problem down to software or some very exotic motherboard/CPU issue.

Basically, if I start up a game (most are in Steam, but it crashes on non-Steam games and demos too) then about 5-15 minutes in, the game will freeze and I'll see a single frame of the game and the last 100ms of sound repeated over and over).

If I reset the computer at this point (i.e. press the reset button) then I can restart, re-enter the game and IT WILL NOT CRASH AGAIN.

If I perform this reseting-from-the-desktop action BEFORE I play the game then it will not crash at all.

The problem has persisted across Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 updates.

Any ideas?  I'm really confused on this one.

Note: I've disabled all non-MS services and startup programs and that doesn't help.  I swapped out the memory and GPUs (SLI) for identical ones in a machine that doesn't have the problem.  Nothing has worked.

Comment: Have you tried updating your video drivers?

Comment: yeah, about 6 times now.  It's been happening for months and Nvidia have brought out many drivers in that time.  I even rolled back to an early one and that didn't help.

Comment: It's usefully significant that performing a reset in advance prevents the problem from occurring. What must be true of the system *without the reset* such that it will lock up? If you find out what's different between the with and without reset state of the system, you'll find your reason for the lockup.

Comment: Exactly.  The problem is, I have no ideas springing forth...  I've only just got to this point in the last few days (previously I was trying hardware and disabling services), but I'm not sure how to proceed in the diagnosis.  There's nothing unusual in the system event logs (not that I really understand much of what I see).